# How do you append to an array list in realtime database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a database of users with their emails, role and list of contacts.

[image]

I have code to add contacts that when you input into the `EditText`, it checks through the database if the email exists and if it does, it appends the email into the contacts list. However, nothing gets added in my database.

```
    public void searchContacts(final String emailInput){
    final DatabaseReference users;

    users = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
    users.orderByChild("email").equalTo(emailInput).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                if((userSnapshot.child("email").getValue(String.class).equals(emailInput))){
                    users.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("contacts").child(emailInput).setValue(true);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is added, because you haven't create a list yet. To solve this, please use the following code:

```
public void searchContacts(final String emailInput){
    DatabaseReference users = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
    users.orderByChild("email").equalTo(emailInput).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(); //Create the list
            for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                String email = userSnapshot.child("email").getValue(String.class);
                if(email.equals(emailInput)){
                    users.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("contacts").child(emailInput).setValue(true);
                    list.add(email); //Add the email the list
                }
            }

            //Do what you need to do with list
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have that in my signup. I initialize a list with a string so that the list is not empty on initialization. If I follow your code, everytime I run the function wouldn't it create a new list with only one value?

Comment: Yes, because you are passing as an argument a single `emailInput`. So everytime you call this method, is called with a single argument. You cannot declare the `List` outside the callback because it will always be empty, due the asynchronous behavior of `onDataChange()` method. More informations **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method/47853774)**.
So to solve this, you need to get a list of **all** contacts and then check if the email exists? And if it exists, add it to another list, right?

Comment: I kinda understand now. However I tried that and it still doesn't add the email of another user that exists that i entered into the EditText box into the contacts list on my database.

Comment: In this case you should make again your own attempt given the information in the answer/comments, and ask another question if something else comes up.

Comment: Why does my function not go into the for loop?

Comment: As I already advised you, please post another fresh question sa we can help you. I cannot be much of a help without seeing the code.